# How can I detect which features are supported in the remote environment?

Tags: intern

What's the API to find out "which features and APIs a remote environment supports"?  In particular to find out if keyboard actions (like tabbing between form fields) are supported.

Note that http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/index.html says this is possible:

> Enhanced capabilities are also exposed to end-users about which features and APIs a remote environment supports, so you don’t have to browser sniff to decide whether (for example) you’re testing a touch-device or a mouse-device. Optional convenience methods are also available for use, and support for chai-as-promised is built in.

I see http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/global.html#Capabilities but although it claims they are global variables, I tried `if(brokenSendKeys)` and it just throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Session capabilities are available on the remote's `environmentType` property.

```
if (this.remote.environmentType.brokenSendKeys) { ... }
```

The "Globals" section in the Leadfoot docs is just a grouping for definitions that are shared throughout the project.