# The Intern: Preferred method of accessing Capabilities of the current session?

Tags: intern, leadfoot

I'm writing an Intern Functional test suite, and I'd like to scan my environment for features in order to skip tests that aren't relevant to the environment.  For example, I never want to run tests that involve touch interactions in browsers that are not touch capable.

My plan was to hook into Leadfoot's `session` object and pick up the `capabilities` property, but after some exploration in Node Inspector I've only been able to get it through `this.remote.session`, which has it hidden behind an underscore.

Is there a better way to get access to the current session's capabilities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect which features are supported in the remote environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183787/how-can-i-detect-which-features-are-supported-in-the-remote-environment)